# Redis relationships between data

Tags: redis

I have a a list in redis containing a sequence of Ids. Each id is unique for a single object which I am storing as a JSON string on a separate key.

So I have something like:

```
redis> LRANGE mylist 0 -1
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
```

And I have separate keys `mylist:one`, `mylist:two`, `mylist:three`.

I am saving the ids to a list in order to build a simple FIFO queue on my application.

What is the most efficient way to get all the ids in mylist and their matching values from each individual key? Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: Why don't you store the JSON strings in your sequence ?

Comment: @Scharron The objects change through time (thus the value stored in the key), while they are still in the list. The unique id makes it possible for me to query them without knowing what the object currently is

Comment: And what about using a Hash to store your objects ? This way you can query `mylist` with a `lrange mylist 0 -1` and then using `hmget my_hash list_of_keys_from_mylist` you can get objects ?

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is probably to use the [SORT command](http://redis.io/commands/sort):

```
# Populate list
rpush mylist one two three
set mylist:one 1
set mylist:two 2
set mylist:three 3

# Retrieve all items with their corresponding values
sort mylist by nosort get # get mylist:*
1) "one"
2) "1"
3) "two"
4) "2"
5) "three"
6) "3"
```